# Bilingual corpora work from the late 1980s

Tags: computational-linguistics, reference-request, corpora, lexicography

Does anyone know if the paper by Warwick and Russell (often cited as below) exists?  I have looked on the [EURALEX](https://euralex.org) website and the authors are not listed as speakers in the 4th Conference.  Maybe the article only exists as a manuscript?  According to WorldCat, the proceedings of that conference have been published, but no library near to me has it.

Susan Warwick and Graham Russell (1990). *Bilingual concordancing and bilingual lexicography.* In: EURALEX 4th International Congress. Málaga, Spain.

Answer (score 2):

G. Russell and J. Carroll have kindly emailed me the answer to my question:

1. The print version of the EURALEX meeting also does not include the paper. And
2. A summary of the 1990 paper can be read in "[Tagging and Alignment of Parallel Texts: Current Status of BCP](https://aclanthology.org/A92-1031.pdf)" (available online) from 1992 Conference on Applied Natural Language Processing.  The idea was to use words from a bilingual lexicon together with the statistics of those words in their respective corpus to determine the regions of text to pair.